# CMR of "All Inverting" balanced line receiver

Tags: operational-amplifier

Walt Jung describes following instrumentation amplifier in his "Op Amp Applications Handbook" (pg 454) saying that the value of R5 (gain adjustment) does not have any interaction with CMR.

My LTSpice simulation shows clearly that there's interaction between R5 and CMR.

Did I understand it wrong?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the CMR is affected? Can you illustrate?

Answer (score 2):

Walt Jung clarified this to me. The interaction I saw was due to increasing op amp net noise, not due to CMR. This simulation model helped to clarify it. The current through the dummy voltage source (V4) does not change when R5 value is changed, demonstrating that CMR is not affected.

[image]